# How can I customize python unitest.py --help?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I know this is possible, I'm a newbie on Python. Looked at nose. But nose is not what we require. There should be some way to customize when I run `python unittest.py --help` on my own. Can any python people throw some light on this on how or where we can change. I'm using python 2.6.6

Comment: Customize it to do what?  You could create a subclass of unittest.TestProgram and set unittest.main to be that subclass but I'm not sure what that would accomplish.  Please clarify by describing what you're trying to do and why "nose is not what we require."

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response.. My Question was to say I wrote a program with python  unittest library. When I run $python unitest.py --help I get normal python unittest library help. I want to modify it, so that I can display all my methods and test cases there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, you're looking at customizing unittest.TestProgram.  You'll want to create something like myunittest.py and in that module you'll do something like:

```
# myunittest.py
from unittest import TestProgram

class MyTestProgram(TestProgram):
    USAGE = """\
Usage: %(progName)s [options] [test] [...]

Options:
  -h, --help       Show this message
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  -q, --quiet      Minimal output

Examples:
  %(progName)s                               - run default set of tests
  %(progName)s MyTestSuite                   - run suite 'MyTestSuite'
  %(progName)s MyTestCase.testSomething      - run MyTestCase.testSomething
  %(progName)s MyTestCase                    - run all 'test*' test methods
                                               in MyTestCase
    """
    # additional changes here...

main = MyTestProgram

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(module=None)
```

Just changing USAGE may be all you really care about as that's the text printed by `python unittest.py --help` but you could obviously customize more.

Note this is specific to Python2.6.  Python 2.7+ uses unittest2 which I'm not really familiar with at this point.